# Rails / RSpec: mail render in spec results in missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

Using `rspec-rails`, how should I test the correct rendering of a mail template?
I started with this test in `spec/views/user_mailer.spec`:

```
describe Mailer do
  it 'sends an message email' do
    render 'send_message'
  end
end
```

It tells me:

```
Failure/Error: render 'mailer/send_message.html.erb'
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing partial mailer/send_message.html with {:formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml, :coffee], :locale=>[:de]}. 
 Searched in: 
   * ".../app/views"`
```

But there is the template I want to render in `app/views/mailer/send_message.html.erb`

How should I spec this? (I want to check if the CSS rules result in the correct color for the footer, which I thought to extract with jQuery-Javascript if there is no better way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use:

```
render template: 'send_message'
```

The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) mention:

> Rails knows that this view belongs to a different controller because
>   of the embedded slash character in the string. If you want to be
>   explicit, you can use the :template option

Note that your template name doesn't have an embedded slash character.